# Scheme: macros or higher order functions for code duplication?

Tags: macros, scheme, racket, higher-order-functions, idioms

I would like to get the results of a function which calls a shell command and returns a string.
I am using racket, and this is my first attempt:

```lisp
(define (run-function)
  (let*
    ([stdout (some-function)]
     [output (process-string stdout)])
  ;; many more lines...
  output))
```

It seems to work well enough, but suppose that I would like to write functions similar to `run-function` for many other shell commands.

To avoid code duplication, I could just define a more general function like this:

```lisp
(define (shell cmd)
  (let*
    ([stdout (cmd)]
     [output (process-string stdout)])
  ;; many more lines...
  output))
```

and then call for example `(shell ls)` or `(shell pwd)`.

An alternative would be using a simple macro:

```lisp
(define-syntax shell
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(shell cmd)
     (let*
       ([stdout (cmd)]
        [output (process-string stdout)])
       ;; many more lines...
       output)]))
```

This would also have the advantage of allowing a more general syntax, for example I could easily change the macro so that it takes as many parameters (commands) as I want, but I am sure the same behaviour could be replicated by writing the higher order function more sensibly.

**Q. What are the pros/cons of writing a higher order function vs a macro? Is there a clear winner between the two?**

Comment: I think a good rule of thumb is to use functions for everything you can, and only when you absolutely _need_ a macro (e.g. to avoid evaluation) do you use it. Not a perfect rule (macros are good for simplifying syntax), but the point stands: use a function if you can.

Comment: @MLavrentyev your comment made me finally get an intuition on why we might like macros: to do some really exceptional tasks like changing the rules by which the interpreter works---something that in most languages would be impossible unless you are prepared to change the interpreter source code itself (and then you would have to remember to use your custom interpreter for running a certain script... the complexity would skyrocket very fast).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with what [@MLavrentyev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4780330/mlavrentyev) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66376735/scheme-macros-or-higher-order-functions-for-code-duplication#comment117349851_66376735), "use a function if you can".

And [the Racket style guide](https://docs.racket-lang.org/style/Choosing_the_Right_Construct.html#%28part._.Functions_vs_.Macros%29) also says:

> Define functions when possible, Or, do not introduce macros when functions will do.

But why? One reason is that if you write `shell` as a function, you can pass `shell` to other functions. You can do the same with macros via the [identifier macro](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/pattern-macros.html#%28part._.Identifier_.Macros%29) feature, but it's much more difficult to do so (and you will effectively end up creating a function anyway).

Another reason is that using macros will make compiled code larger than using functions. This is because macros are expanded at compile-time, and the expanded code is then compiled (into bytecode in Racket BC, machine code in Racket CS). So it's as if you write `(let* ...)` over and over again. If you distribute the compiled or executable Racket program, you wouldn't want the size to be large.

In fact, a good practice when writing a macro is to try to stuff code into functions as much as possible. Instead of writing:

```
(define-syntax-value (debug code)
  (let ([val code])
    (printf "~a evaluates to ~a\n" (quote code) val)
    val))
```

it would be better to write it as:

```
(define (debug-core expr val)
  (printf "~a evaluates to ~a\n" expr val)
  val)

(define-syntax-value (debug code)
  (debug-core (quote code) code))
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems one of my sources, Kent Dybvig's book The Scheme Programming Language could be interpreted as not agreeing 100% with the racket style guide. At some point in the book he says: *Syntactic extensions, or macros, are used to simplify and regularize repeated patterns in a program, to
introduce syntactic forms with new evaluation rules, and to perform transformations that help make programs
more efficient.* which made me think it is OK to use macros to try to minimise code duplication.